# Atom: native macOS spell check and autocorrect?

Tags: macos, atom-editor, spell-checking, autocorrect

Is there a way to have the native macOS (OS X) spell check and autocorrect in the Atom editor? (for English words)

That would be useful for example with Markdown files.

Comment: I opened a [Feature Request Issue](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/15797) on the atom github for this point.  Please add a thumbs-up or any additional points / suggestions!